# Bell character as Fields separator in Python print output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am fairly new to Python and need a little help here.

I have a Python script running on Python 2.6 that parses some JSON.

**Example Code:**

```
if "prid" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
    print data[p]["products"][n]["prid"],

    if "metrics" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
        lenmet = len(data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"])
        i = 0
        while (i < lenmet):
            if (data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricId"] == "price"):
                print data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricValue"]["value"]
                break
```

Now, this prints values in 2 columns:

```
prid price    
123 20    
234 40
```

As you see the fields separator above is `' '`. How can I put a field separator like BEL character in the output?

**Sample expected output:**

```
prid price    
123^G20    
234^G40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, your `while` loop doesn't increment `i`, so it will loop forever, but I assume that was just a copy & paste error, and I'll ignore it in the rest of my answer.

---

If you want to use two separate `print` statements to print your data on one line you can't avoid getting that space produced by the first `print` statement. Instead, simply save the prid data until you can print it with the price in one go using string concatenation. Eg,

```
if "prid" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
    prid = [data[p]["products"][n]["prid"]]

    if "metrics" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
        lenmet = len(data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"])
        i = 0
        while (i < lenmet):
            if (data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricId"] == "price"):
                price = data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricValue"]["value"]
                print str(prid) + '\a' + str(price)
                break
```

Note that I'm explicitly converting the prid and price to string. Obviously, if either of those items is already a string then you don't need to wrap it in `str()`. Normally, we can let `print` convert objects to string for us, but we can't do

```
print prid, '\a', price
```

here because that will give us an unwanted space between each item.

---

Another approach is to make use of the new `print()` function, which we can import using a `__future__` import at the top of the script, before other imports:

```
from __future__ import print_function

# ...

if "prid" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
    print(data[p]["products"][n]["prid"], end='\a')

    if "metrics" in data[p]["prdts"][n]:
        lenmet = len(data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"])
        i = 0
        while (i < lenmet):
            if (data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricId"] == "price"):
                print(data[p]["prdts"][n]["metrics"][i]["metricValue"]["value"])
                break
```

---

I don't understand why you want to use BEL as a separator rather than something more conventional, eg TAB. The BEL char may print as ^G in your terminal, but it's invisible in mine, and if you save this output to a text file it may not display correctly in a text viewer / editor.

---

BTW, It would have been better if you posted a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on your actual printing problem, rather than all that crazy JSON parsing stuff, which just makes your question look more complicated than it really is, and makes it impossible to test your code or their modifications to it.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring. I apologies for complicating the question or for that matter posting only part of the question. So the whole idea is I have some data set and I need to add price and title to it. The price and title can be fetched by calling a service. Now I was thinking of fetching the id, price and title from service and then adding it to a mysql table. Then joining with the other data on id. The title has ' ' and  when I try to load the data that has ' ' as the delimiter it would split the title. Hence, I wanted to use BEL character. Anyways, both of your solutions worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @donny I'm glad that my answer has helped you. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Instead of using BEL, try using TAB. Or maybe you can wrap strings that have spaces in quotes. I don't use mysql, but that _could_ work.